# How to select common keys of dictionaries in Python and sum values?

Tags: python

I have a list of nested dictionaries and I would like to select the key:value pairs where key=`value` and sum all values. How could I do that with a single line of code ?

```
[{'default': {'AA': {'quantity': 0.05215832, 'value': 2940.4440669952},
              'BB': {'quantity': 493.96434168, 'value': 888.9823555432}},
 'basic': {'CC': {'quantity': 911.84309821, 'value': 911.84309821}},
 'expert': {'DD': {'quantity': 0.00833, 'value': 0.036579529000000006},
          'AA': {'quantity': 0.000823, 'value': 0.303896042},
          'RR': {'quantity': 0.000166, 'value': 0.0035026000000000002},
          'FF': {'quantity': 0.00183, 'value': 0.057991785}}}]
```

I can select keys with:

```
[[d[i].keys() for i in [k for k, v in d.items()]]]
```

But I'm unable to go further.

Comment: Give an example of what you would like your output to look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```py
lst = [{'default': {'AA': {'quantity': 0.05215832, 'value': 2940.4440669952},
              'BB': {'quantity': 493.96434168, 'value': 888.9823555432}},
 'basic': {'CC': {'quantity': 911.84309821, 'value': 911.84309821}},
 'expert': {'DD': {'quantity': 0.00833, 'value': 0.036579529000000006},
          'AA': {'quantity': 0.000823, 'value': 0.303896042},
          'RR': {'quantity': 0.000166, 'value': 0.0035026000000000002},
          'FF': {'quantity': 0.00183, 'value': 0.057991785}}}]

lst_sum = sum(value['value'] for key in lst[0].keys() for value in lst[0][key].values())
print(lst_sum)
# Prints 4741.6714907044
```

This executes a list comprehension, then sums up all of the values. It first iterates through each level (`'default'`, `'basic'`, and `'expert'`) then iterates through each letter pair of it (`'AA'`, `'BB'`, etc).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this sum values of the first dictionary `default` but not `basic` and `expert`

Comment: @Florent I know, I just corrected it. It should work properly now.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
input_nested_dict = {'AA': {'quantity': 0.05215832, 'value': 2940.4440669952},
                     'BB': {'quantity': 493.96434168, 'value': 888.9823555432}}
    
sum([input_nested_dict[key]['value'] for key in input_nested_dict.keys()])
```

I assumed based on the selection key code snipped you gave that you work on a per dictionary basis and not on the entire list at once.

You can remove the brackets to have a generator instead of a list comprehension:

```
sum(input_nested_dict[key]['value'] for key in input_nested_dict.keys())
```

Comment: The `input_nested_dict` in your example is only one dictionary of the list but there are 3